# Sending a javascript AJAX request triggers multiple page loads

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have searched but cannot find an answer to this issue. I am calling an asynchronous javascript file and the php page it calls makes a database entry twice.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                //document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
                return;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://example.com/api/tracking/index.php?cid=" + get["clientId"] + "&refUrl=" +  encodeURIComponent(siteURL) + "&auk=" + get["auth"],true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The index php page does an insert and returns the new row id. The alert in the successful response corresponds to that id, but there is another entry made one millisecond before. I assume this is happening because the page is being accessed until it gets the ready state of 4. The question is how do I stop or bypass this?

Comment: are you really supporting IE5 and IE6?

Comment: @Ramy is your question relevant to answering the OP's, or were you just making trite observations about what the OP intends to support?

Comment: The script is being called from sites I do not have control over, other than giving the site owner a code snippet.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. Is `get` defined? What are "multiple page loads?" Do you mean multiple requests are being made in the `window.onload` function and you have no idea why?

Comment: The index.php file makes a database entry. There are 2 entries made every time the page with the javascript is loaded. I am assuming the index.php is being loaded multiple times. Yes, the get variables are set and being passed fine.